# Duplicated Labels in included files on LyX

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, include

I'm working on a document structure template composed of several stand alone documents that can also be included in another document generating a "top level" document. The problem is that all the stand alone documents have the same pre-defined labels for tables in figures (since it is a template, make sense to have all that already pre-defined) so when I compile them in the "top level" document the labels are maked as "duplicated" and the in text cross-references go crazy. Curiously, the List od Tables and List of Figures are woking fine.

Here some example:

`Document-A.lyx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This document describes subject "A".
\begin{figure}
\caption{First Figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}
```

`Document-B.lyx`: (identical to Doc A, since it is using the same template)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This document describes subject "B".
\begin{figure}
\caption{First Figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}
```

`Document-C.lyx`: (identical to Doc A, since it is using the same template)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This document describes subject "C".
\begin{figure}
\caption{First Figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}
```

`Document-D.lyx`: (this oneinclude all others)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This document has a description of all subjects.
\section{Chapter 1}
\include{Document-A.tex}
\section{Chapter 2}
\include{Document-B.tex}
\section{Chapter 3}
\include{Document-C.tex}
\end{document}
```

When opening Document-CD.pdf, the lines `See Figure~\ref{fig:1}.` on Chapters 2 and 3 will be all "See Figure 3", since the label `fig:1` on these files will be renamed to "DUPLICATED-fig:1". I don't understant why LyX renames all duplicated labels to the same name, but that's what happening.

Is there a way to correct this issue, preventing LyX to automatically rename the labels or setting a renaming rule, or the only way to solve this issue will be renaming all labels manually?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I would probably go to lyx.org and add an issue in their bug tracker. It could be that it's expected behaviour, that they've only implemented a check, and adding of the `DUPLICATED` string to make it more obvious which labels are duplicated, in which case your issue can be a feature request. If LyX is supposed to make unique labels but doesn't, then it's a bug.

Comment: Hi! I'll take a look in lyx.org to see if anything like this has been reported. If not, I'll report myself. Thanks

Comment: Let's say LyX gets the labels right, i.e. the way you want them. What should it do with all those '\ref{fig:1}'? Does fig:1 in file C reference the figure in file A, B or C? How's LyX supposed to know that? Make your labels unique!

Comment: Yes, after struggle a while with this issue I came to this conclusion, I have to make them unique. Inside Documents A, B and C I have a macro, lets call it "\name", that is defined as the subject. So I use \let and \renewcommand inside Document D to rename the labels and avoid all this mess:

\let\newlabel\label
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\newlabel{\name #1}}
\let\newref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\newref{\name #1}}

Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: @JPHanke: The redefinition of `\label` etc. is 'dangerous'. Use the `xr` or `xr-hyper` packages in order to grab labels and cross-referencing information from other documents, then apply `\externaldocument[doc-A]{Document-A} etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP says in the comments that the problem is solved.